# Load Image from Xaml

Tags: wpf, image

Could I load a image from xaml file?
for example: having a folder IMAGES that contains all of images resources. These images were not added to project. I want to load an image from xaml file as following code:

```
<Image Source="/IMAGES/gift.png" Height="70" Width="70" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Is it possible or do I have to load this from behind code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) with siteoforigin authority like this:

```
<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/IMAGES/gift.png" 
       Height="70" Width="70" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Comment: It doesnt run. Because gift.png wasnt added to my project.

Comment: I just tried it with an image located under my Debug folder.
Note that the path needs to be relative to the running assembly. So if your compiled exe is in \bin\Debug folder, file needs to be in \bin\Debug\IMAGES\gift.png.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a folder of images in your project folder then try this:

```
static string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        static string debug = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        static string bin = Path.GetDirectoryName(debug);
        static string DefaultLayoutFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(bin);
        public string xmlDefaultLayoutFile = DefaultLayoutFilePath + "\\IMAGES\\gift.png";
```

and add for all images properties change them to copy always to output folder.
it will surely work.